# Column chart overlaps to one line when there's just a group of data

Tags: highcharts

As you can see from: http://jsfiddle.net/EwZsS/1/.
Four columns overlap to one line when there's just a group of series data, like that shows below.

```
series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [[Date.UTC(2013, 0, 6), 49.9]]

        }, {
            name: 'New York',
            data: [[Date.UTC(2013, 0, 6), 83.6]]

        }
  ]
```

And it will well perfomed when I add another group of series data(i.g. http://jsfiddle.net/EwZsS/2/).

I don't know where the problem is. How could I fix the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that each series has exactly one point, so Highcharts aren't able to calculate required space for each series. For such cases you need to use `pointRange`, see: http://jsfiddle.net/Fusher/EwZsS/3/

Ref: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.pointRange